# Allign contents inside a div as a column without modifying parent layout

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm facing is the following:

I want to achieve the following layout for my project:

[image: ht]

In the red rectangles I want an image, on the orange a text code and in the green some big text.
The current output of the html and css code is the following

[image]

The flags and the code seems to push out the contents of the other div to another row, and also the container of it is not working as intended. This was my first attempt:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">   
    <link href="bigNamesStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Big Names</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=round>T16</div>

    <div id=leftFencer>
        <div class=flagContainer> 
                <img id=flagIcon src="res/flags/AFG_dp.bmp">
                AFG
        </div>

        <div> MANDARINI OJERAS</div>
    </div>


    <div class=rightDiv> 
        <div id=rightFencer>
            <div>MANDARINI OJERINI</div>
            <div class=flagContainer>
                    <img id=flagIcon src="res/flags/AFG_dp.bmp">
                    AFG
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=imgContainer> <img id=logo src="res/icon.gif"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

bigNamesStyles.css

```
html{
    background: black;
    font-family: 'Impact';
}

#round{
    font-size:calc(4vw + 4vh);
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    background: navy;
}


#leftFencer{
    margin-top:calc(2vw + 2vh);
    font-size:calc(6vw + 5vh);
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    width: 90%;
    background: red;
}

.rightDiv{
    text-align: right;
}

#rightFencer{
    margin-top:calc(1.5vw + 1.5vh);
    font-size:calc(6vw + 5vh);
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    width: 90%;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block
}

.imgContainer{
    text-align: center;
}

#logo{
    margin-top:calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);
    width:calc(6vw + 3.5vh);
}

#flagIcon{
    width:calc(7vw + 5.5vh);
}

.flagContainer{
    font-size:calc(3vw + 2.5vh);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
```

In this approach I see why is this happening, but I'm unsure about how I can use flexbox in the containers to achieve the desired layout. Is there any easy way to organize the divs to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following new CSS:

```
#leftFencer,
#rightFencer,
.flagContainer{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  padding: .1em;
}

#leftFencer > div:not(.flagContainer),
#rightFencer > div:not(.flagContainer){
   margin: 0 .3em;
}

.flagContainer{
   flex-flow: column;
}
```

Basically create inline flexboxes to position the elements the way you want them, then add a little margin and padding to make things look less crowded

```css
html {
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Impact';
}

#round {
  font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: navy;
}

#leftFencer {
  margin-top: calc(2vw + 2vh);
  font-size: calc(6vw + 5vh);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  background: red;
}

.rightDiv {
  text-align: right;
}

#rightFencer {
  margin-top: calc(1.5vw + 1.5vh);
  font-size: calc(6vw + 5vh);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block
}

.imgContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: calc(0.7vw + 0.7vh);
  width: calc(6vw + 3.5vh);
}

#flagIcon {
  width: calc(7vw + 5.5vh);
}

.flagContainer {
  font-size: calc(3vw + 2.5vh);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

#leftFencer,
#rightFencer,
.flagContainer{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .1em;
}

#leftFencer > div:not(.flagContainer),
#rightFencer > div:not(.flagContainer){
   flex: 1
}

.flagContainer{
   flex-flow: column;
}

div#rightFencer {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id=round>T16</div>

<div id=leftFencer>
  <div class=flagContainer>
    <img id=flagIcon src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"> AFG
  </div>

  <div> MANDARINI OJERAS</div>
</div>


<div class=rightDiv>
  <div id=rightFencer>
    <div>MANDARINI OJERINI</div>
    <div class=flagContainer>
      <img id=flagIcon src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"> AFG
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=imgContainer> <img id=logo src="http://placekitten.com/200/250"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way to provent the name boxes to be smaller if the text can't fill it completely? Because now if I put some shorter text the box is being reduced

Comment: @Norhther yeah just remove `width: auto;` from the first new style rule

Comment: but then the text and icons are going to be align to the left of the container. Is there a way to let the text be centered and the flags in the original position? I mean, at the left and right of the div, respecting the margin and padding.

Comment: @Norhther I added `div#rightFencer {justify-content: flex-end}` does that answer your question?

Comment: a little bit, but the problem is that when the flag is properly placed the text should be centered in the space left by the flag. I'm sorry if the original question image wasn't clear enough...

Comment: @Norhther `#leftFencer > div:not(.flagContainer),#rightFencer > div:not(.flagContainer){ flex: 1 }` See my edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204309/discussion-between-norhther-and-symlink).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix duplicate Ids. Each element should have a unique Id. If you want to group them use a class instead.

To prevent image from pushing text to next row, you can use float:left on your image.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First we start with one layout

```
<div class="container"> // wrapper
    <div class="flag">  // flag and short name section
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
        <p>AFG</p>
    </div>
    <div class="name"> // full name section
        <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now let's use `flexbox` to align everything

```css
/* we make the container a flex container */

.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}


/* we don't have to do anything for the flag section because the image will decide the width */

.flag {
  background: green;
}


/* flex:1 on the right div to fill the remaining space */

.name {
  flex: 1;
}


/* to make everything visible, not needed*/

.container * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And now we can just copy paste and apply `flex-direction:row-reverse;` to the container and we'll have everything aligned to the right without changing the markup

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  
  flex-direction: row-reverse;/* Added */
}

.flag {
  background: green;
}

.name {
  flex: 1;
}


/* to make everything visible, not needed*/

.container * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And now the final output

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.flag {
  background: green;
}

.name {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


/* to make everything visible, not needed*/

.container * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Added class left with the property flex-direction: row-reverse; -->
<div class="container left">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

There's many ways to dock the divs to the right or left, here i simply used margins

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.flag {
  background: green;
}

.name {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


.dock-right{
  margin-right:10vw;
}
.dock-left{
  margin-left:10vw;
}





/* to make everything visible, not needed*/
.container * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container dock-right">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container left dock-left">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/60">
    <p>AFG</p>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <p>MANDARINI OJERAS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to @simlink's answer you can also use boostrap for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container img-responsive">
        <div class="row" style="background-color:#000080;">
            <div class="col-12" style="height: 100px;">
                <center>
                    <h style="font-size: 75px; color: cornsilk; font-family: fantasy;">T16</h style="font-size: 75px; color: cornsilk;">
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container img-responsive">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2" style="height: 100px;">
                        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
                            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                <img style="height: 75%; width: 75%;" src="1.jpg">
                                <p>some text here</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8" style="background-color: green;">
                        <m  style=" text-align:center; font-size: 75px; color: cornsilk; font-family: fantasy;">MANDARIN OJERAS</m>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2" style="height: 100px;"></div>
                    <div class="col-8" style=" background-color: green;"">
                        <m  style="text-align:center ; font-size: 75px; color: cornsilk; font-family: fantasy;">MANDARIN OJERAS</m>

                    </div>

                    <div class=" col-2" style=" height: 50px;">

                        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
                            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction:column;">
                                <img style="height: 75%; width: 75%;"  src="1.jpg">
                                <p>some text here</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/y5prvqex/1/